# feasibility of PCIe16 and PCI digital display cards together?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express, pci

I want to run two digital display cards. I have an Radeon 5450 which I believe is PCIe16.  I have only one PCIe16 slot.  If I buy a second digital display card, it would have to go into a PCI slot, of which I have two empty.  I would not be using the analog output from the built-in display hardware on this G45 motherboard.

Is there any reason why this would not work?

I want to do this for both Windows 7 and Ubuntu, dual booting.

Comment: There's no way to answer this question usefully without knowing what it is you're trying to accomplish. What do you hope to gain from this?

Comment: I just want two digital outputs (not mirrored).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put a PCI-E video card and a PCI video card in the same computer, and you can connect a monitor to each and have them both work.

"If I buy a second digital display card" it has to be a PCI card, not a PCI-Express card.  Different blades, for different slots.  Like [This one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814161010).  Sure, it has a VGA output, but it also has a DVI output.  There are multiple different cards like this.